# USB stick is getting boot errors

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, rufus

I am new to Ubuntu. I used Rufus to use my USB as bootable Ubuntu installation media. At first I was seeing a lot of errors and then it finally worked, but after five minutes every application I launch crashed almost instantly, so I reinstalled it using the USB stick, but now it's showing the following errors.

```
wn-block (0,0)
2.0058731 CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/8 Not tainted 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22
04. 1-Ubuntu
2.0059011 Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP ProBook 4540s/17F6, BIOS 68IRR
Ver.
F. 68 04/11/2019
2. 0059291
Call Trace:
2. 0059491
‹TASK>
2. 0059691
dump_stack_1v1+0x48/0x70
2. 0059941
dump_stack+0x10/0x20
2. 0060161
panic+0x35a/0x3a0
2. 006039]
mount_block_root+0x27b/0x280
2. 0060641
mount
_root +0x83/0xb0
2. 0060851
prepare_namespace+0×f5/0x200
2. 0061071
kernel_init_freeable+0×1c1/0×200
2. 006130]
__pfx_kernel
_init+0x10/0x10
2.0061541
kernel_init+0x1b/0x200
2. 0061751
_pix_kernel
_init+0x10/0x10
2. 0061981
2. 0062201
ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x50
</TASK＞
2. 0064581
e:
Oxffffffff80000000-0xfffffffffffffff)
Kernel Offset: Oxb200000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation rang
on unknown-block（8,0） 1---
2.0065161 ---I end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that the root partition failed to mount. (i.e. primary disk volume with Ubuntu) or that the kernel doesn't support the filesystem on the device.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414655/not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0#414662

Ubuntu has a [tutorial on creating a bootable USB for ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows?ref=sy34.net#1-overview). If you haven't checked that out already, please do.
In my experience sometimes [Balena Etcher](https://etcher.balena.io) works better than Rufus, you could try that too.

To create an installation drive for Ubuntu it should just overwrite the binary of the USB with the iso image. There's no magic to it even though these applications may seem mysterious sometimes.

If you have a Linux system somewhere already you could use dd. However this might seem complicated at first, if you're new to ubuntu and Linux.

- Download the Ubuntu iso.
- Run lsblk to see which disks are currently in the computer.
- Insert your USB drive and find the new /dev/sd* i.e. /dev/sdc

Run `sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu<name-version>.iso of=/dev/sd<letter> bs=1m status=progress` 1m may have to be 1M depending on the version of dd you are using.

***Be careful not to overwrite a drive you don't mean to overwrite!***

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html

Comment: Thank you I will be sure to try that